# Using CASE on COUNT in MySQL

Tags: mysql, count, sum, case

I have a table (mytable) similar to this:

```
Names
-----
John  
Harry 
James
Harry 
John
James 
Harry 
Billy
```

1. I would like to count the number of times each name appears.
2. I would like to multiple each count by a number, depending on the number of appearances. So if a name appears once, multiply by 2, if it appears twice, multiply by 3 etc.
3. I would like to then SUM all these output values.

This would be my desired output:

```
Names | numbers_count | multiplied
----------------------------
John  | 2             | 6
Harry | 3             | 12
James | 2             | 6
Billy | 1             | 2

SUM =  26
```

So far I have this, I think I need to use the CASE function and then presumably the SUM function, but I am failing miserably! I have tried using local variables for this aswell but to no avail.

```
SELECT
Names,
COUNT(Names) AS number_count

FROM mytable

GROUP BY Names
```

The use of this would be, for example, in a tiered pricing model.

EDIT: Thank you very much for that answer Juan Carlos Oropeza, you are correct. However, I should have posed the question better. The real problem I am working on requires a system like:

```
IF (1 <= numbers_count <= 3) multiplied=(numbers_count*2) 
IF (4 <=numbers_count <= 6) multiplied=((3*2)+((numbers_count-3)*3))
```

so i would like to use the CASE functionality in this example so I can apply it to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    *,
    COUNT(Names) AS COUNT_OF_N,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(Names) <= 3
             THEN COUNT(Names) * 2
         WHEN COUNT(Names) <= 6
             THEN COUNT(Names) * 3 
    END AS Multiplied
FROM
    mytable
GROUP BY
    Names
```

This should do what you need.  You'll just have to make sure you cover every case.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    Names,
    COUNT(Names) AS number_count,
    COUNT(Names) * (COUNT(Names) + 1) AS multiplied
FROM mytable    
GROUP BY Names
```

For the sum you need another query

```
SELECT SUM(multiplied)
FROM (    
        SELECT
            Names,
            COUNT(Names) AS number_count,
            COUNT(Names) * (COUNT(Names) + 1) AS multiplied        
        FROM mytable    
        GROUP BY Names
     ) T
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that speedy answer, that's really kind, you are correct. However, I should have posed the question better.

The real problem I am working on requires a system like:
IF (1 <= numbers_count <= 3) multiplied=(numbers_count*2)
IF (4 <= numbers_count <= 6) multiplied=((3*2)+((numbers_count-3)*3))
etc.